# CSS Align div next to image

Tags: html, css

I want to embed a picture on my website and give a brief description about it on the right side of the picture. However when I resize my browser, the description either overlaps the text (absolute position) or the image size becomes unusable (relative positioning).

P.S.: I have already tried `min-width` using percentages, em, px, relative and absolute positioning.

```css
.img {
    height: 200px;
    padding-left: 9%;
    padding-top: 1%;
    width: 154px;
}

.desc {
    position: absolute;
    right: 50%;
    text-align: right;
    top: 28.5%;
}
```

```html
<img class="img" src="https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*mk1-6aYaf_Bes1E3Imhc0A.jpeg" alt="image" />
<div class="desc">
<p>
    <h2>description</h2>
    random description<br> of an image<br> as an example
</p>
</div>
```

Codepen link:
https://codepen.io/c-ca11Ahan69/pen/QWKKxZd

Solutions in pure CSS are appreciated

Comment: Flexbox may be useful here

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have offered a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Absolute positioning is tricky and should be used sparingly. You have much better options for this, such as inline-block display and flexbox. I'd refactor.

Comment: Also, block-level elements like `h2` don't belong inside paragraphs. It's a violation of the HTML spec and doesn't conform to the _semantic structure_ principle.

Comment: See the definitive [flexbox guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/kbg7espf/).

Answer (score 0):

I have seen your code and added [Flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to it. You have to read the documentation to understand it better.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <style>
      .img{
          width: 154px;
           height: 200px;
         padding-top: 1%;
          padding-left: 9%;
  } 
      .desc{
     margin-left: 10px;
 }

 .flex{
   display: flex;
 }
    </style>
    <div class="flex">
  <img class="img" 
 src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" alt="image">
 <div class="desc">
  <p><h2>description</h2>
  random description <br>
  of an image<br>
  as an example</p>
  </div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you must use inline display to fix your problem.

```
.img{
  width: 154px;
  height: 200px;
}
.desc{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

good luck

Answer (score 0):

I have made a few changes to your implementation and here is why:

1. You want to use flex box for this. It is a powerful CSS tool which is meant to empower (among other things) alignment of blocks, so I added a div as a wrapper to allow it to leverage flex.
2. Renamed the classes to be more descriptive.
3. Removed the CSS class for the `img` element as it is not relevant to this snippet. You can add one for your own use if you require it, just change the CSS to adapt to it.
4. Removed all styles used for absolute positioning, this is no longer needed as we are using flexbox.
5. Media queries, this is important to achieve a different look/feel when the browser shrinks. I added one implementation as an example and you can change as you wish (resize the browser to see what happens).

```css
.image-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-bwtween;
}
.image-container > img {
    height: 200px;
    width: 154px;
}
.image-description {
    margin-left: 10px;
    text-align: right;
}

/* change the viewport size to what you need */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .image-container {
      flex-direction: column;
  }
  .image-description {
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*mk1-6aYaf_Bes1E3Imhc0A.jpeg" alt="baby-yoda-image" />
  <div class="image-description">
    <h2>Description</h2>
    A random description<br> of an image<br> as an example
  </div>
</div>
```